# WordPress Cron how to find out my event recurrence?

Tags: cron

In my plugin I'm able to set a cron event like so:

```
wp_schedule_event(time(), 'daily', 'myhookname');
```

But want I want to do is be able to find out what recurrence I have set for `myhookname`.

The reason why is that I'm offering a setting to allow the recurrence to be changed. What I need to do is check if the recurrence setting has changed from what its currently set as and if so remove the event and reschedule the event with the new recurrence.

So if there a function like this:

```
$recurrence = wp_current_event_recurrence('myhookname'); // returns hourly/daily/etc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I've found it: `wp_get_schedule('myhookname')`

Edit: yes this works as I want it.